# Countability of the set of weighted graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Could you help me find the solution for this problem that consists in finding out wether the set of all weighted and finite graph is countable of not?

As a reminder, a weighter graph can be seen as a pair $(G,f)$, where $G = (V,E)$ is a graph with the set of vertices $V = {1,\ldots,n}$ for $n$ natural number.
The function $f\colon E\to\mathbb N$ matches each edges with a natural number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can you describe a weighted finite graph by a string unambiguously (that is, each string corresponds to at most one graph)? If so, the set of weighted finite graphs is countable.

Comment: I had the idea of matching the weight of each edges to the string of prime number. What do you think about this ?